# How do I get file modified / creation date using Mule SFTP connector?

Tags: mule, sftp

I am using the SFTP connector to move files around in Mule. The connector works fine, but I would like to get the file modified date while processing the file. Is it possible to retrieve and if so, how can it be done.

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an inboundProperty from the endpoint called 'timestamp'.

`#[message.inboundProperties.timestamp]`

The value will be an epoch like '1477574688000' that you can convert to whatever format you want.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, SFTP does not provide this like the ftp and file connector. It will be added in Mule 4 technically as part of the new ftp module: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7175

Comment: Thanks for your message Ryan. Unfortunately, that property does not seem to exist in the inboundProperties.  Referencing it comes back with a null.

Comment: Sorry, i thought you asked FTP. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way, using the MuleContext, to get this information from the SFTP connector or ask the connector to go get it?

Comment: No I don't think so. there is a zip file with the modified SFTP transport classes to fix the issue. you can build the transport yourself with those modifications.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source ftp connector on GitHub with this feature: https://github.com/rbutenuth/ftp-client-connector

The inboundProperty.timestamp contains a java.util.Date.